# What is insight and can we develop it?

Tags: knowledge, cognitive-sciences

One person really helped me to develop a subject knowledge and I thank him saying: "Thank you so much for your time and knowledge!". He said, you can be more knowledgeable than me, but what it takes to really understand is the **insight**.

So, my question is how one develop insight systematically?

Comment: This seems to be a good fit for cognitive science unless you're asking about it in generic terms.

Comment: Some systematic things one can do is (1) maintain one's health, (2) get adequate rest, (3) pay attention and practice what one wants insight into.

Answer (score 3):

One should begin by asking insight into what?

For example, there is such a thing as mathematical and physical insight. The disciplines aligned with this - mathematics and physics - have come up with many pedagogical devices to help train intuition in such a way that the possibility of insight becomes developed.

So on this reading insight is indeed trainable though like many other things, it also depends on a persons capacity and potential for insight.